# How can I derive functional properties of (the solutions of) this simple functional differential equation?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, functional-equations

I've not yet finished a course in functional analysis so I'm unsure how to go about this, but I've always been fascinated by a simple functional differential equation I concocted for almost no reason.
$$
f'(t) = f(t/a)
$$
where $a$ is any real constant, and now as a pet project, I'd like to explore it.

Just recently I realized I might be able to derive functional properties of it thanks to [a partially answered question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764869/can-we-make-extrapolations-about-functional-properties-from-differential-propert/4764898?noredirect=1#comment10119412_4764898).

However, based on their response, I got contradictory results, and I'm hoping someone can explain it and how to fix it.

Suppose $f(t)$ is a solution. Then define a new function $g(t) = f(t+y/a)$ where $y$ is any real constant, independent of $t$.
$$
\frac{d}{dt} g(t) = f(t/a + y/a) = g(t/a)
$$
Now let $h(t) = f(t)f(y/a).$ Then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}h(t) = f(t/a)f(y/a) = h(t/a).
$$
So it appears as though $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ satisfy the same differential equation, and thus I may be able to conclude $f(t/a+y/a) = f(t/a)f(y/a)$.

But this is a contradiction! This is only satisfied by the exponential function, which would only be the case when $a = 1$! What's going wrong here? How do I fix this?

My guess is the "uniqueness" property isn't satisfied here, at least not in the same way, though I don't understand "why" it's not satisfied.

Comment: May I ask what level of functional analysis course you are taking? This will help potential answerers tailor their response to what your background is.

Comment: I've taken several undergraduate and then graduate general real and complex analysis courses. I had hoped to get a professional response on the choice of history function and initial conditions to rectify the failure of uniqueness of the solutions to these functional differential equations here, but functional differential equations are a very very niche subject, so it's unlikely, and this is probably a waste of time as it has been so far, unfortunately. I initially appreciated the efforts, but no longer after finding how abrasive and combative this community is.

Comment: Please be aware that this community is made up of individuals, and not all of them will necessarily treat newcomers with kid gloves. I do think the conversation in the comments got out of hand and needed cutting off sooner, just so everyone can have a break and clear their heads. But it's a global effort, and moderators can arrive late, or be keeping an eye and miss the best moment ask everyone to chill.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I understand your point, but the problem is not just that one individual did something questionable by being weirdly combative and derailing my question, it's that *multiple* other members of your community condoned it! As if to say "oh yeah, this is how professional mathematicians should act". Not only that, but they didn't even address virtually *any* of the content of my question, so it was all for nothing except for the pretty looking graph.

Comment: It might well be that your question is something that no one here can say much about, being as you say fairly niche. It might also be true that by presupposing what tools will need to be applied, you did not attract the right users. Also, saying in your first sentence that you haven yet finished a course on something makes you look less experienced than you are (there is an undergrad course on functional analysis at my university! However, _I've_ never taken such a course...) Better to present your problem and then ask if functional analysis is the best tool to use, and what can be said.

Comment: Not addressing any content of the question was perhaps hindered by not giving all the info: saying you'd got the power series solution and exhibiting it would have saved people time. I don't have more to add, but please take this as friendly professional advice to get the most out of MO in future.

Comment: This equation is a special case of the [pantograph equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation#Examples), itself a special case of a delay differential equation.

Comment: Aha! In that case, see this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.06734, _Basic theory of a class of linear functional differential equations with multiplication delay_, by Cheng-shi Liu. In particular section 2, and equation (15), in section 3.

Comment: Thank you two for looking into this, I'll take a look and see what I can make sense of.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal N}$It appears that your functional differential equation (FDE) should rather be written as
\begin{equation}
    f'(t)=f(t/a). 
\end{equation}

Then we can first try expanding $f(t)$ into a (possibly formal) power/Laurent series:
\begin{equation}
    f(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty c_kt^k. 
\end{equation}
Using your FDE and equating the coefficients at the same powers of $t$, we get
\begin{equation}
    c_{j+1}(j+1)=c_ja^{-j}
\end{equation}
for all $j\in\Z$. So, $c_k=0$ for $k=-1,-2,\dots$, whereas
\begin{equation}
    c_k=\frac{c_0}{k!}a^{-(k-1)k/2} 
\end{equation}
for $k=0,1,\dots$. So, we get
\begin{equation}
    f(t)=c_0 f_a(t),\quad f_a(t):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}a^{-(k-1)k/2}. 
\end{equation}
The latter series converges for some or, equivalently, all $t\ne0$ if and only if $|a|\ge1$. For all $t$,
\begin{equation}
    f_1(t)=e^t,\quad f_{-1}(t)=\sin t+\cos t.
\end{equation}

For values of $|a|>1$ in general, an explicit expression for $f_a(t)$ does not seem to be available.

---

Here are parts of the graphs of $f_a$ for $a=2$ (red), $a=-2$ (green), and $a=-1$ (blue):

[image]

---

As for your claim that, if two functions $g$ and $h$ "satisfy the same differential equation", then $f$ and $g$ must be the same: No reasons for that claim are provided by you or seen otherwise. For ODEs, such uniqueness holds (under some regularity conditions) only if $f$ and $g$ satisfy the same initial conditions. In fact, even for your FDE, it is clear that there is no uniqueness here: if $f$ is a solution, then $cf$ is also a solution, for any constant $c$.

Comment: It's comforting you got the same power series I did, but it also looks like you're stuck as much as I am. Although, how exactly did you obtain $f_{-1}(t) = \sin(t) + \cos(t)$?

Comment: P.S. upvote for the pretty graphs!

Comment: @CheeseBlues : Where did you get the power series? And why did you not mention it in your post? And why having such a series is being "stuck"?

Comment: @CheeseBlues : As for $f_{-1}(t)=\sin t+\cos t$, you can just take the series for $f_a(t)$, substitute there $a=-1$, simplify $(-1)^{-(k-1)k/2}$ for $k=0,1,\dots$, and then compare the resulting series with the Maclaurin series for $\sin t+\cos t$.

Comment: Because the series itself doesn't help me much with "functional" properties. If you have a very very very simple Taylor series, like for e^x, then you can (still tediously) derive some basic properties. But I can't rely on only basic techniques for e^x here, I need a broader scope of ideas than that, which is where functional analysis comes in.

Comment: The conversation here was not at all about addressing the question, I've left only the comments that are about the actual focussed problem at hand. Unless there is more that can be said that is constructive, let's just give it a break. Whether or not the OP's suggestion that functional analysis might help is the right idea, debating that is less helpful than either giving some mathematical insights, or simply saying "that's all I've got".

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume for simplicity that $f(t)$ is a nice function which tends to
$0$ at infinity faster than any power, and consider the Mellin transform
$$F(s)=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}f(t)\,dt\;.$$
Then modulo computational errors your functional equation implies that the function
$$\phi(s)=\dfrac{F(s)a^{s(s+1)/2}}{e^{i\pi s}\Gamma(s)}$$
is periodic of period $1$, so you can choose for $f$ the inverse Mellin transform of $e^{i\pi s}\Gamma(s)a^{-s(s+1)/2}P(s)$ for any reasonable function $P$ of period $1$, such as a linear combination of $e^{2i\pi ns}$
with $n$ integral.

Comment: Okay, so another approach is taking integral transforms. I'm fairly confident $f(t)$ is defined over a rather large domain, I'd be surprised if it wasn't defined over any closed subset of real numbers, though I can't for sure it decays at $\infty.$ 

Unfortunately however, I don't understand a portion of what you're saying, so you've left me with a function $F(s)$ in the Mellin domain, whereas I'm looking for properties in the time domain $t$. But perhaps you're implicitly suggesting I multiply $F(s)$ with some other (bounded?) periodic function and take the inverse-transform.

Comment: To clarify, I would appreciate clarity on the intent and motivation of your response.